Почему не работает автозаполнение ячеек в Google таблицах?
Имеется простая формула, которую мне нужно скопировать в соседние ячейки, так чтобы в каждой следующей ячейке увеличивался на 1 номер ячейки в формуле: CONFIG!$I1, CONFIG!$I2, CONFIG!$I3, ... и так далее.
Я установил знак $ перед буквой, чтобы при перетягивании (автозаполнении) она не изменялась.
Я ожидал что при выделении первой ячейки с формулой я получу инкремент в каждой последующей ячейке: $I1, $I2, $I23. Но нет во всех последующих формулах я получил одно и то же: $I1, $I1, $I1, ...
Попробовал по другому, формулы в первой и второй ячейках заполнил вручную, выделил их и перетянул за маркер. В итоге, во всех последующих ячейках получил: $I1, $I2, $I1, $I2, $I1, $I2, ...
Если убрать вообще знак $, то при перетягивании изменяется только буква: I1, J1, K1, ...
Почему не работает и как исправить?

